# Prevent double entry in session storage

Tags: php, session

I’m trying to work on login with login details in array, all stored in this script.

I added session arrear in which each login will be stored in session.txt, I want a situation whereby I won’t have duplicate of a login in the session.txt to prevent double login, if you already logged in, you can’t login again.

The first username in this script is prevented to login twice meanwhile others can login, What I intend to do is to avoid double entry in my session.txt.

Here is my code:

```
<?php session_start(); /* Starts the session */

    /* Check Login form submitted */    
    if(isset($_POST['Submit'])){
        /* Define username and associated password array */
        $logins = array('Emmanuel' => '1234','John' => 'Faith123','Favour' => '12345','Abbey' => 'Godisgood');

        /* Check and assign submitted Username and Password to new variable */
        $Username = isset($_POST['Username']) ? $_POST['Username'] : '';
        $Password = isset($_POST['Password']) ? $_POST['Password'] : '';

        /* Check Username and Password existence in defined array */        
        if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){
      $handle = "sessions.txt";
      $data = file_get_contents($handle);
$line = explode("\n", $data);
foreach ($line as $user) 
{
if($Username==$user)
{
  echo"You can not vote twice";
}
else
{
            /* Success: Set session variables and redirect to Protected page  */
            $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];
      $string = $Username . "\r\n";
      $handle = fopen("sessions.txt", 'a');
      fwrite($handle, $string);
      fclose($handle);
            header("location:../president");
            exit;
        } }else {
            /*Unsuccessful attempt: Set error message */
            $msg="<span style='color:red'>Invalid Login Details</span>";
        }
    }
?>
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>LOGIN</title>
<link href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div id="Frame0">
  <h1>LOGIN</h1>
</div>
<br>
<form action="" method="post" name="Login_Form">
  <table width="400" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="1" class="Table">
    <?php if(isset($msg)){?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="center" valign="top"><?php echo $msg;?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2" align="left" valign="top"><h3>Login</h3></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right" valign="top">Username</td>
      <td><input name="Username" type="text" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td align="right">Password</td>
      <td><input name="Password" type="password" class="Input"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>&nbsp;</td>
      <td><input name="Submit" type="submit" value="Login" class="Button3"></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```